# Homogeneous systems Constant Coefficients Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

For the following homogeneous system of constant coefficients initial value problem, I have used a method involving matrices and confirmed that I have found the correct eigenvalues, however, I have not been successful in finding the solution to the overall initial value problem.

Consider the system of differential equations:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = -1.6x + 1y
\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = 1.25x - 3.6y
\\
x(0)= 3
\\
y(0)= 7
$$
Please see the steps of my work below.
$$
\vec x=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1.6 && 1\\
-1.25 && -3.6\\
\end{bmatrix}x
\\
$$
characteristic equation:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
-1.6-r && 1\\
-1.25 && -3.6-r\\
\end{vmatrix}
\\
(-3.6-r)(-1.6-r)-(1.25)(1)=0
\\
r^{2}+(\frac{26}{5})r+(\frac{451}{5})=0
\\
r_1=\frac{-41}{10}, r_2=\frac{-11}{10}
$$

for eigenvalue $r_1$:

$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     -1.6-(\frac{-41}{10}) & 1 & 0\\
-1.25 & -3.6-(\frac{-41}{10}) & 0\\
    \end{array}
\right] 
\\
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     2.5 & 1 & 0\\
-1.25 & 0.5 & 0\\
    \end{array}
\right] 
$$
RREF
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     1 & 0.4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{array}
\right] 
\\
\xi_1+0.4\xi_2=0
\\
$$
let:
$$
\xi_1=1,\xi_2=\frac{-4}{10}
$$
for eigenvalue $r_2$:

$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     -1.6-(\frac{-11}{10}) & 1 & 0\\
-1.25 & -3.6-(\frac{-11}{10}) & 0\\
    \end{array}
\right] 
\\
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0\\
\frac{5}{4} & -\frac{5}{2} & 0\\
    \end{array}
\right] 
$$
RREF
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     1 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{array}
\right] 
\\
\xi_1-2\xi_2=0
\\
$$
let:
$$
\xi_1=1,\xi_2=2
$$
General Solution:
$$
x(t)=c_1e^{-\frac{41}{10}t}
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{4}{10}\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}+c_2e^{-\frac{11}{10}t}\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Solving for particular solution by applying initial conditions:
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     -\frac{4}{10} & 2 & 3\\
1 & 1 & 7\\
    \end{array}
\right] 
$$
RREF:
$$
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
     1 & 0 & \frac{55}{12}\\
0 & 1 & \frac{29}{12}\\
    \end{array}
\right] 
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1\\
c_2\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{55}{12}\\
\frac{29}{12}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\vec{x}(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{11}{6}e^{-\frac{41}{10}t}+\frac{29}{6}e^{-\frac{11}{10}t}\\
\frac{55}{12}e^{-\frac{41}{10}t}+\frac{29}{12}e^{-\frac{11}{10}t}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: This seems (to me) very correct ! Did I miss something ?

Comment: I submitted this answer online for an assignment, but it is incorrect. The system prompts for two answers: x(t) and y(t) - in that case, x(t) should correspond to the first row and y(t) should correspond to the second row of my final answer above, correct?

Comment: Again, your solution is correct. It must read $$x(t)=
-\frac{11}{6}e^{-\frac{41}{10}t}+\frac{29}{6}e^{-\frac{11}{10}t}$$
$$y(t)=\frac{55}{12}e^{-\frac{41}{10}t}+\frac{29}{12}e^{-\frac{11}{10}t}$$

Comment: Yes, you were right, this solution is correct - it just happened that I had inputted the answer incorrectly. Thank you for checking my work.

Comment: You are very welcome ! It was my pleasure.